# How to update & restart a Node app with Mercurial following a push? (Equivalent of git post-receive in hg)

Tags: node.js, mercurial, mercurial-hook

I've worked with Git to accomplish this before, but require Mercurial for another project. My Git recipe included a `post-receive hook` that looked like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ec2-user/www
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
```

Which would refresh my working app directory every time I pushed to the remote repo on my server. I'd then run my app with [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor): `supervisor server.js`, which would watch for file changes and restart Node following a git push / file change.

My question is what's the best way to accomplish this with Mercurial. I've looked into the `changegroup` hook as a similar alternative, but I can't find any example hooks. Thanks!

---

**Update:** My Implementation

Per answer & comment below, I went with the `changegroup` hook. Specifically, in `myrepo/.hg/hgrc` I used:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update && /path/to/restart/script.sh
```

I went with a basic shell script to restart Node vs. installing node-supervisor per above, for this project. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Restarting Server" >> /logpath/server.log
sudo pkill -x node
sudo node server.js >> /logpath/server.log &
echo "Changegroup Hook Executed, Server Restarted"
exit 0
```

I have only one Node process running, so pkill (all) works for me. I'm also running the server.js straight out of my repo directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Hooks part](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) of the Red Bean book. Especially scrolling down to the **Hooks Reference** portion may be of use, e.g.:

> `changegroup`—after remote changesets added

Comment: rather than `incoming` use `changegroup`.  If someone does a `hg push` that sends 10 changesets the `incoming` hook will be run 10 times, but `changegroup` would be run only once.

Comment: Thanks guys! I've updated my question to reflect my working implementation.